# Weigthing a dataset

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm looking for possible algorithms/techniques to give weight to a data set. I have a set of let us call them ID's which need to be weighted based on different criteria.  To make the example a little bit easier, the beginning weight (value) of every record will be 1.

For example we use the following data set

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Age</th><th>Postalcode</th><th>Status Insurance A</th><th>Marital Status Number of childeren</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>30</td><td>10000</td><td>ON HOLD</td><td>SINGLE</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>35</td><td>15000</td><td>ACTIVE</td><td>DIVORCED</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>36</td><td>15000</td><td>ACTIVE</td><td>MARRIED</td><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Next to the data set we have a set of rules we need to apply to give it a weight (addition):

- ages (> 10 and < 20):  **+0.5**
- ages (> 20 and < 30):  **+0.7**
- ages (> 30 and < 99):  **+0.85**
- martial status : (married) : **+0.50**
- martial status : (divorced) : **+0.45**
- martial status : (single) : **+0.35**
- status insurance (ACTIVE) : **+0.05**
- status insurance (ON HOLD) : **+0.1**

Now we need to apply these rules to the data set, so for example record with ID=1 would have a weight of

```
  1 + 0.85 (age>30) + 0.1 (status: ON HOLD) + 0.35 (martial status : SINGLE) = 2.3
```

This is just a small example, but the set of rules is more complex can be manipulated by the user and weights can be changed.

I could off-course implement this the naive way, just write some hard coded logic to go over the data set record by record and test if the rule applies.

I was however wondering if there are better more generic solutions to this kind of problem ?

Comment: I've been looking around and I'm wondering if a rules engine would be a good solution here..  I did a little experiment with Drools en this seems quite nice...

Comment: The question is where you want the weighting to be used... should it be stored in the database, determined runtime when records are used, be available in several clients or just one, is it a selection/sorting criterium, how often are the criteria changed, etc etc.